# Git returns partial branches list from Github

Tags: git, github, freerdp

I'm trying to checkout a specific branch (`rdp_gfx_plus_fixes`) from a certain repo ([Remmina](https://github.com/FreeRDP/Remmina)) on Github.

I cloned the repo, but when I do `git fetch -r` I cannot see the branch I need:

[image]

I also tried `git ls-remote origin`, but the branch I'm interested in isn't listed.

I'm pretty sure this is trivial, but still, I cannot figure it out.

Thanks!

Comment: Please don't post *pictures* of text.  Just post the text itself (properly formatted).

Comment: Are you sure you're running your `git` commands in the correct directory?  The `Remmina` repository doesn't have branches named "stable-1.0" and "stable-1.1" (but the `FreeRDP` repository does). Based on the directory name I see in your question, it looks like you're simply running things in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found the issue! [As per documentation](https://github.com/FreeRDP/Remmina/wiki/Compile-on-Ubuntu-16.04), I was cloning from

```
git clone https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP.git
```

When actually the Remmina repo I need is

```
git clone https://github.com/FreeRDP/Remmina.git
```